# PostgreSQL row_to_json and is not null

Tags: postgresql

Below is my table1

```
-------------------------------------
category_name | col1_name | col2_name
-------------------------------------
postgres      | 1         | null
-------------------------------------
SAM           | null      | 2
-------------------------------------
MariaDB       | 1         | 3
-------------------------------------
```

Below is my query

```
select row_to_json(row) as "tableRow"
from (
    select 
      t.category_name as "categoryName",
      ( select distinct on (col2_name) 
          st.col2_name as "col2Name"
        from Table1 st
        where
          st.col2_name = t.col2_name and
          st.col2_name is not null )
    from Table1 t
) row;
```

Below is my result

```
-------------------------------------------
tableRow
-------------------------------------------
{"categoryName":"postgres","col2Name":null}
-------------------------------------------
{"categoryName":"SAM","col2Name":"2"}
-------------------------------------------
{"categoryName":"MariaDB","col2Name":"3"}
-------------------------------------------
```

**How do I return my result as below?**

```
-------------------------------------------
tableRow
-------------------------------------------
{"categoryName":"postgres"}
-------------------------------------------
{"categoryName":"SAM","col2Name":"2"}
-------------------------------------------
{"categoryName":"MariaDB","col2Name":"3"}
-------------------------------------------
```

col2_name shouldn't return if there's a null value in it.

I did try include 'col2_name is not null' in the parent query but it removes the whole row.

Please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can jsonb_strip_nulls

```
select jsonb_strip_nulls(to_jsonb(row)) as table_row
from ( 
  ....
)
```

Comment: Many thanks.. I did try on select json_strip_nulls(row_to_json(row)) as "tableRow" and it does return the same